# EventSourcing, Aggregates – working with invariants without doubling them

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I am playing with event sourcing techniques in my application on pretty basic level, however I have encountered an conceptual issue. Lets move straight to example.

ProductAggregateRoot.php

```
public function changePrice(ChangeProductPrice $command): self
{
    if ($this->availability->equals(Availability::UNAVAILABLE())) {
        throw CannotChangePriceException::unavailableProduct();
    }

    if ($this->price->equals($command->newPrice)) {
        throw CannotChangePriceException::priceHasntChanged();
    }

    $this->recordThat(
        new ProductPriceChanged($this->price, $command->newPrice)
    );

    return $this;
}
```

Right now, I would like to create some other method (or even domain service, doesn't really matter) which would simply:

1. Fetch current price and availability from external source
2. Try to update price on aggregate.
3. Try to update availability on aggregate.

As you can see, while updating price I am checking some business invariant such as you cannot change price if product is unavailable and you cannot change price if its value hasn't changed. If any of the invariants are broken, throw an exception.

Now, when in my domain service I want to change price and availability basing on external data source. Right now, I simply did some try catch block like so:

```
try {
    $aggregate->changePrice(new ChangeProductPrice(
        $productId,
        $state->getPrice()
    ));
} catch (CannotChangePriceException $ex) {
}
```

One try-catch block for price, another for availability and so on. It works but I have feeling that it is simply wrong and hacky. I would be way more comfortable with simple if block and methods/specifications like `CanChangePrice()`. However I would need to double use it – both in service and in concrete method itself, which also doesn't sound good.

The question is: how do you guys handle such things? It seems like a very trivial problem but still I haven't found an solution which would make me feel good about it.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

- Why not have a "change price and availability" command?  This better captures the intent of updating both and allows invariant check to have better contextual knowledge (e.g. if we're updating availability to available, then the current availability is meaningless because it's a relic of a prior time).
- I'm a little suspicious of considering an attempt to change the price to what's actually the current price to be an error.  The command, to my mind, is expressing a desire that the price become the desired price, so if that desire's already met, why make that an error?  Returning `$this` (effectively shrugging and saying "sure") seems better, and doesn't force the requester to know the current price (which they can't, strictly speaking, already know).

Comment: 1. Thought about it. However, I would like to be able to modify price and availability on its own, without passing both parameters in every scenario. Even assuming it would work, I would encounter the very same problem in another program flow while trying to update i.e. product name and price at the same time. That's why I would like to keep it atomic, so I can compose different flows as long as given parameters are not tightly coupled with each other.

Comment: 2. That's a good point. Indeed, I can simply skip emitting events in that case.. As far as it is true and very helpful insight, my question is little more generic - let's assume there are some other invariants - in which cases I should say "sure" and when I should stop it and actually throw an exception? If the business rule would be "price cannot drop more than 30% at once", should that be already an exception? If so, we are back to the main question.

Comment: Having two commands instead of one isn't being atomic though, because each command is atomic, so you're, if anything, "molecular".  Making something outside the aggregate string together multiple commands (and have to handle rolling back the first command if the second one fails).  Within the aggregate, your implementation of "change price and availability" can delegate to aggregate primitives (some sort of fluent or monadic API might be helpful, if your language supports).

Comment: As in example, I am directly calling an aggregate method with a command as a parameter. When all methods are already called on aggregate, only then persisting happens – after all, it is one transaction anyway.

I could go with three methods – for price, availability and both combined. However, in that case I would need to double a lot of stuff inside (invariants, emitting events, changing state etc.). In combined method I could just call internally other methods but then again – I need to handle exceptions.